# Call Stored Procedure In Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I am using Entity Framework to call a stored procedure. The stored procedure looks like this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[AdminContracts] 
    @StatusId INT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT ..
```

and my code looks like this:

```
public virtual ObjectResult<AdminOrder> GetAdminOrders(int orderStatus)
{
    return ((IObjectContextAdapter) this).ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreQuery<AdminOrder>("AdminContracts", new SqlParameter("@StatusId", orderStatus));
}
```

which seems to be correct from the other questions on SO

However, it causes an exception:

> Procedure or function 'AdminContracts' expects parameter '@StatusId', which was not supplied

Looks ok to me but obviously I am missing something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
public virtual ObjectResult<AdminOrder> GetAdminOrders(int orderStatus)
    {
        return ((IObjectContextAdapter) this).ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreQuery<AdminOrder>("EXEC AdminContracts @StatusId", new SqlParameter("StatusId", orderStatus));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`ExecuteStoreQuery<T>` Method 
Executes a query directly against the data source that returns a sequence of typed results.
so it can be user to run T-SQL statement you can check its [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.objects.objectcontext.executestorequery?view=netframework-4.8) 
so your code it will be as following:

```
public virtual ObjectResult<AdminOrder> GetAdminOrders(int orderStatus)
{
        return ((IObjectContextAdapter) this).ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreQuery<AdminOrder>("EXEC AdminContracts @StatusId", new SqlParameter("StatusId", orderStatus));
}
```

but if you want to call stored producer or function you can use `ExecuteFunction<TElement>` Method
Executes a stored procedure or function that is defined in the data source and mapped in the conceptual model, with the specified parameters. Returns a typed ObjectResult.
you can check its [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.objects.objectcontext.executefunction?view=netframework-4.8)

so your code it will be as following:

```
public virtual ObjectResult<AdminOrder> GetAdminOrders(int orderStatus)
{
  return ((IObjectContextAdapter) this).ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreQuery<AdminOrder>("AdminContracts", new ObjectParameter("@StatusId", orderStatus));
}
```